# THREE.ShaderMaterial on JSON model from blender

Tags: three.js, glsl, blender

three.js r.73

I've used a simple shader which makes checker on faces. Here is a code for VertexShader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

and FragmentShader:

```
uniform vec3 color1;
uniform vec3 color2;
uniform float scale;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
  vec2 center = -1.0 + 2.0 * vUv;
  vec2 uv = floor(center.xy * scale);
  if(mod(uv.x + uv.y, 2.0) > 0.5){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color1, 1.0);
  }else{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color2, 1.0);
  }
}
```

It works for primitive objects but for a models from Blender in json format it doesn't.

**Question**: Why shader doesn't work for json model?

I've prepared [jsfiddle with json object(white) and primitive box.](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/z56p4acL/)

Comment: the uv coords in your model is empty

Comment: @gaitat That's right. Can I put answer for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer put @gaitat

```
"uvs": [[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.749957(...)]],
```

JSON model must have UV map, [I've updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/z56p4acL/1/).

r.73